# alert will not stop after onsubmit event - javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html

The Ajax request is being sent continuously and I am not sure why

placing return false in multiple areas of the code.

```
//when user clicks on create channel
    document.querySelector('#add-channel').onclick = () => {
      // pop up modal
      modal1.style.display = "block";
      // Initialize new request
      document.querySelector('#form1').onsubmit = () => {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const chatroom = document.querySelector('#chatroom').value;
        const username = localStorage.getItem('name');
        request.open('POST', '/add_chatroom');
        // Callback function for when request completes
        request.onload = () => {
            // Extract JSON data from request
            const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            // Update the result div
            if (data.success) {
                // get the data that was returned.
                // add it back to the list
                document.querySelector('#contacts').append(li);
            }
            else {
                alert('chatroom already exists');
            }
        }
        // add data to send to the server
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('chatroom', chatroom);
        data.append('username', username);

        // Send request
        request.send(data);
        return false;
      };
    };
```

The post request won't stop everytime I click ok even though the event should only trigger when the form with id #form1 is submitted. It triggers even when i click ok for the alert.

Comment: `console.log(data)` to see if it has a `success` property that is truthy.

Comment: Just look for your curly braces that's where the issue exists.

Comment: @StackSlave it is still the same, on clicking the ok or dismissing the alert button, the event is triggered again for onclick #add-channel even if it is not supposed to. The add-channel's type is of modal, does that affect the event trigger in any way? Thank you~!

Comment: Assuming `document.querySelector('#add-channel')` is your submit button, get rid of that wrapper altogether.

Comment: @StackSlave - I got rid of it and it is still resubmitting it...Could it be that my flask application is run under io? Does this affect Ajax requests?

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the browser from Firefox to Microsoft edge to solve the onsubmit re-running issue, why this works is beyond my knowledge.